# Campo DropDownList e Checkbox acionando uma função javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Tenho dois campos DropDownList e Checkbox que são responsáveis por inserir valor em um inputtext

**Como fazer o código javascript saber o status enviado true ou false do CHECKBOX para a função.**

**DropDownList**

```
<div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.DropDownList("PlanoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

**Checkbox**

```
<div class="checkbox">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnuncioDestaque)
</div>
```

**Como fazer DropDownList Checkbox acima, acionar o Javascript abaixo**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#PlanoId, #AnuncioDestaque").on("change focusout", function () {

           //Pegar Status do Checkbox se vei true ou false
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Sem jQuery

```
document.getElementById('PlanoId').checked;
```

Com jQuery

```
$('#PlanoId').is(':checked');
```